# Mudando conteúdo de uma TD

Tags: php, javascript, html, table

Eu estou tentando fazer com que numa função o conteúdo de uma célula TD da minha tabela seja modificado.

Quero passar de:

```
<td id="tdDespesas" style="border-right:1px solid #FFFFFF;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">{label_orcadoRealizado_despesas}
    <img id='btnOne' src='{raiz}images/layout/row_plus.gif' onclick='showLines()' title='Extender' style='cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px;'/>
    <img id='btnTwo' src='{raiz}images/layout/row_minus.gif' onclick='hideLines()' title='Diminuir' style='cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px;'/>
</td>
```

Para:

```
<td id="tdDespesas" style="border-right:1px solid #FFFFFF;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">{label_orcadoRealizado_despesas}
</td>
```

Preciso fazer isso porque a função seria uma impressão em PDF e, infelizmente, estão aparecendo os códigos dos botões btnOne e btnTwo. Colocar hide ou display: none nos botões não adiantam pra isso, por enquanto.

Qual seria a melhor solução? InnerHTML ou InnerContent infelizmente não funcionam.

Answer (score 0):

Se o problema é a impressão, então utilize `@print` no CSS, para poder ocultar os botões somente no ato da impressão.

Exemplo:

```
@media print{

  .btnOne, .btnTwo { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: Eu não sei, mas acredito que o correto seria `@media print { ... }` em @WallaceMaxters